# Unable to set time of process clock, do I need some privileges?

Tags: c, time, runtime-error, clock, invalid-argument

In my C program, I am trying to set the time of the process clock by using the command `clock_settime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID,...)` but I am getting the invalid argument error `EINVAL`.

```
#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
        struct timespec a;
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID,&a);
        fprintf(stdout,"Current process time: %d %d\n",a.tv_sec,a.tv_nsec);
        
        a.tv_sec=0; 
        a.tv_nsec=0;
        
        fprintf(stdout,"Resetting process time status: %d\n",clock_settime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID,&a));
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID,&a);
        fprintf(stdout,"Current process time: %d %d\n",a.tv_sec,a.tv_nsec);
        return 0;
}
```

Strace output:

```
clock_settime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, {0, 0}) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
write(1, "Resetting process time status: -"..., 34Resetting process time status: -1
```

This is my first time playing around with clocks. Do I need some privilege to be able to set the time of this clock, or is there some logical error?

Comment: Probably only `root` can set the clock.  You shouldn't normally need to do this in user code.  If you this is for testing, you should use a mock instead.  Changing the clock while things are running can cause weird errors.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks for your response. The `clock_gettime()` commands are executing successfully, so I don't think `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` is not supported in my system.

Comment: @JoelFan I tried to set it as the `root` user but it is giving me the same error. This [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_getres.2.html) lists further possibilities as to why I am getting `EINVAL`. One of them states *"The **clockid** specified in a call to clock_settime() is not a settable clock."* Does "*settable*" here mean *only settable by the superuser* or *not settable at all*? Do you think this could be the cause? Just trying to confirm.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri: I guess that is what is meant by the sentence "On Linux, this clock is not settable." in the manpage you just linked to. :-) (In the description of `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`)

Comment: If only I had read further...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, the `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` and `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` clocks are not settable. This is noted in various places in the [man 2 clock_getres](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_getres.2.html#NOTES) manpage, including the `NOTES` section linked to above:

> According to POSIX.1-2001, a process with "appropriate privileges" may set the `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` and `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` clocks using `clock_settime()`.  On Linux, these clocks are not settable (i.e., no process has "appropriate privileges").

(That text was moved from `BUGS` to `NOTES` about a year ago, so if you haven't updated your manpages recently, you'll find it in `BUGS`, close to the end. About the same time that it was moved to `NOTES`, it was also noted in the individual descriptions of the two clocks.)

Recent versions of the manpage also list that as a possible reason for the `EINVAL` return code (it was always a possible reason, but only recently documented).